# MySQL and Amazon RDS DBA user

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a new MySQL setup in Amazon RDS.  Created the "Master User" when launching the instance.  Able to connect without issue.  Then noticed that user was not a DBA.  When trying to fix this in MySQL Workbench the following error appears;

```
Error changing account MyDBA@%%: Access denied for user 'MyDBA'@'%%' (using  password: YES)
```

How do I fix this?  Is in Amazon RDS someplace?  In Workbench?  New to MySQL so sorry for the simple question but I cannot find an answer.

edit:  Just to be clear MyDBA is the master user created in RDS when the instance created, so I have no other account to log in as

Comment: You will need to be logged in as root or another DBA to change the privileges on MyDBA

Comment: That is the problem, I am logging in with the user that was created with instance in Amazon RDS

Comment: @Xaphann That user is neither root nor a DBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User roles are not an actual MySQL Server concept.  That's something the Workbench developers just made up, in their characteristically feeble attempts to be "helpful."

> To aid in assigning privileges to MySQL Server users, MySQL Workbench introduces the concept of Administrative Roles.
>
> [...]
>
> **DBA**: Grants all privileges
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html</sup>

The problem is, "all privileges" are not available on RDS.

> In order to deliver a managed service experience, Amazon RDS [...] restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.CommonDBATasks.html</sup>

Specifically, you cannot have the [`SUPER` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) on RDS.  Not even the master user has this.

You also cannot grant a privilege to a user that you don't possess yourself, so creating a different user and trying to give them the DBA "role" will not work, either.